# How to get full list of Gatsby.js routes/endpoints in Cypress tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, frontend, gatsby

I am currently writing some E2E tests with Cypress for a Gatsby based project.

For one test in particular, i'd like to loop through all pages of my Gatsby site, and in order to achieve this, I need a test fixture (e.g. `endpoints.json`) which includes an array of all urls.

I've tried the following methods (but all have limitations):

**1. Running a node script to check the folder structure in the `src/pages` folder**

Limitation - This doesn't account for dynamically generated pages in `gatsby-node.js` with `graphql`

**2. Running a node script to scrape URLs in the `sitemap.xml` file generated with `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`**

Limitation - The plugin only generated a sitemap.xml file in prod builds and not in dev (cypress runs a dev server)

Would be more than grateful if anyone has a suggestion for how we would get a full list of Gatsby endpoints in this environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty cool new plugin for Cypress that will allow you to get the endpoints in your fixtures and env variable, called [gatsby-cypress-endpoints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-cypress-endpoints). coreyward's answer is perfectly valid, but this should allow you to get the endpoints only when you run Cypress.

Comment: Seems disingenuous to be calling out “a pretty cool new plugin” like this when you are the author of it.

Comment: Totally agree with @coreyward. A "disclaimer: I am the author of this plugin" would be the "SO way" of announcing something like this.

Answer (score 3):

You might just want to generate a file in the desired format on-build using the data in GraphQL:

```
// gatsby-node.js
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs").promises

exports.onPostBuild = async ({ graphql }) => {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
    {
      pages: allSitePage {
        nodes {
          path
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return fs.writeFile(
    path.resolve(__dirname, "all-pages.txt"),
    data.pages.nodes.map(node => node.path).join("\n")
  )
}
```

This creates a `.txt` file with each page’s path on a line. You could also just write out the data as JSON by passing in `JSON.stringify(data.pages)` as the second argument to `writeFile`, though.

Comment: This approach is great but the function only works on *build* not with the dev server. Right now my CI (GH actions) runs the dev server for testing. Is there a workaround that doesn't involve recommitting this file every time the sitemap changes?

Comment: @TylerAuer You can do the same thing during the `createPages` API (i.e. replace `onPostBuild` with `createPages` in the code snippet above) if you want to run something like this during development.

Comment: Thanks @coreyward! I figured that out eventually. I think it could be helpful to others, so I'm glad the alternative is in the comments.

Comment: @TylerAuer @coreyward Gatsby v3 now creates pages on demand with `gatsby develop`. This means that using both of the above solutions only generates a subset of endpoints. Have you guys experienced this?

Comment: No, decisions like that and others that go undocumented in the changelog are precisely why I have no intention of “upgrading” to v3.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the above approaches will cause issues if I've already started the dev server (`gatsby develop`) and then add a file that causes a new page to be created? That's not a big deal for my use case, but good to know about.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that with more recent versions of Gatsby (particularly v3) you may have to set the env variable `CI=true` for the suggested solutions to work.

I believe this is because of changes to the development experience where pages & queries are processed [on-demand instead of upfront](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/gatsby-v3/).

The following [flags](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/v2.28/#feature-flags-in-gatsby-configjs) `FAST_DEV` / `QUERY_ON_DEMAND` may be responsible for this behaviour.